# Servlet external config file requires full path

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've looked at a number of related cases here on stackoverflow related to this, but mostly deal with the situation of deciding where to put external files and access them, which is quite clear.

In my situation, I have a Java EE application that needs to use a third party library that reads an external config file to determine the location of another file.  I am using Eclipse and Tomcat.

The external config file has a line that reads like: `FILENAME=[path]`, where path is expected to be the full path name to the file.

I have no way of knowing how they access the file, save to say that specifying `/WEB-INF/classes/file` or just `file` does not work, the library can't find it.  However when I put the full name `/Users/.../file` on my local machine, it can find it.

As this is intended to be deployed on production server in the cloud, is my only solution to put the needed file in cloud storage, then set the config file to point to this absolute location ?

Comment: Sounds like the third party library has a severe design bug (relying on unportable local disk file system instead of on portable Java classpath). Tell which library exactly it is, then we could check whether it's open source or not and propose the correct workaround/solution.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  Agree, I mentioned this to them but they seem unwilling or unable to deal with it at the moment, would be much better to use getResource or some variant of such based on ServletContext.  I am referring to the HiTRUST Java toolkit for their payment gateway, so it's definitely not open source.

Comment: Any idea what API they use to read the file? Is it just `FileInputStream`? If so, I'm not sure you have any options here other than putting the file in a place where you always know it can be reliably found. Maybe something like `/the.file` and then always arrange to have `/the.file` be a symlink to the place where the file really is. Another option would be to, upon deployment of your application, copy your config file from the application into `/tmp/the.file` and then set your external config file to point to `/tmp/the.file`.

Comment: No idea, but by the behavior I'm seeing so far, it's likely FileInputStream.  You might be right that I have to put it somewhere where it can always be reliably found...